# Query IN with Realm Android

Tags: java, android, realm

so i try some query with Realm with my project, i want to get all Detail menu with personsInMenu has Status True. i want to get all the prices and get the size of how many people has Status True with that Menu.

this is my model

```
public class DetailMenu extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    private int MenuID;
    private int Quantity;
    private String MenuName;
    private int MenuPrice;
    public RealmList<PersonInMenu> personInMenus;

    //all the setter getter.. its too long if i input those setter getter

}

public class DetailPerson extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    private int PersonID;
    private String PersonName;
    private int PersonPrice;

}

public class PersonInMenu extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    private int PersonID;
    private boolean Status;

}
```

this is my query:

```
RealmResults<DetailMenu> personSize = realm.where(DetailMenu.class).equalTo("personInMenus.PersonID", Person.get(0).getPersonID()).equalTo("personInMenus.Status", true).findAll();
```

hopefully someone can help me on this.

Comment: What's wrong with your current query?

Comment: i dont know, when i want to look the size, here is the output

`I/nyobain: [DetailMenu = [{MenuID:0},{Quantity:35},{MenuName:hahaha},{MenuPrice:50},{personInMenus:RealmList<PersonInMenu>[6]}], DetailMenu = [{MenuID:1},{Quantity:50},{MenuName:hehe},{MenuPrice:5},{personInMenus:RealmList<PersonInMenu>[6]}], DetailMenu = [{MenuID:2},{Quantity:5},{MenuName:Tes},{MenuPrice:8},{personInMenus:RealmList<PersonInMenu>[6]}], DetailMenu = [{MenuID:3},{Quantity:5},{MenuName:gege},{MenuPrice:10},{personInMenus:RealmList<PersonInMenu>[6]}]]`

Comment: Please edit the question with the additional information instead of writing it in comments

Comment: Querying relationships can be tricky. Please read https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#link-queries